# error: rpmdb: damaged header #1439 retrieved -- skipping

Tags: centos

Could you please any one help me?

I'm getting following error message "error: rpmdb: damaged header #1439 retrieved -- skipping." while I'm trying to install Samba server. I tried Google search but unable to solve my problem.

Comment: What distribution are you using? If it is Fedora, please add the full output and the command you are issuing.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question I'm using CentOS kernal ver 2.6.32-573.8.1.el6.x86_64  CentOS release 6.7 (Final)

Comment: sudo yum -y install samba I'm using this command to install samba

Comment: You shoudn't tag this question as ubuntu or fedora, but anyway I'm going to write an asnwer that I think it is the one that will solve your issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems that the RPM database is corrupted in some way, so you should try to restore it:

```
sudo rm -f /var/lib/rpm/__db*
```

and then rebuild it:

```
sudo rpm --rebuilddb
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thank you skytux my problem has been solved. and sorry for the wrong tagging.

Comment: I'm glad you solved your issue! :)

Comment: You are free to vote if the answer helped you!! ;)

Comment: I'm unable to vote your answer.

Comment: Hmmm, didn't have that file/directory, the rebuild command trew another, different error, but a second rebuild command finished without error. After, the initial error about damaged headers was gone.